# Is there a way to transfer a value of an int from one object to another within the same class via method in c#

Tags: c#, oop

```
class Bank
{
    private String accoutNumber;
    private double credit;

    public String AccountNumber
    {
        get { return accoutNumber; }
        set { accoutNumber = value; }
    }

    public double Credit
    {
        get { return credit; }
        set { credit = value; }
    }
        
    public Bank() { }

    public Bank(String accoutNumber)
    {
        this.accoutNumber = accoutNumber;
    }

    public Bank(String accoutNumber, int credit)
    {
        this.accoutNumber = accoutNumber;
        this.credit = credit;
    }

    public void addBalance(int amount) { credit += amount; }

    public void vyber(int amount)
    {
        if (amount > credit)
            return;

        credit -= amount;
    }

    public void transfer(int amount, String accoutNumber)
    {
        if (amount > credit)
            return;

        //else transfer from one object to another
    }
}
```

(in another file i am using the transfer method to transfer credit from one object to another, i just don't know how to do that, also i am not using any files for database, it is as simple as it could possible be)

```
Bank object1 = new Bank("1234567890/1234", 10000);
Bank object2 = new Bank("7845213154/1448", 7000);
object1.transfer("7845213154/1448", 2000)
//object1's credit = 8000
//object2's credit = 9000
```

Comment: well, what is `object1`, and how does that relate to account numbers, and what is available in the current instance? I might *expect* something more like a lookup, i.e. `someAccountDirectoryService[finalAccountNumber].AddBalance(amount)`; I wouldn't use `+=` because you'd almost certainly want the change to at least be atomic, i.e. either some lock primitive, or `Interlocked`

Comment: @MarcGravell it is just a random object of the class; account number is more like an ID of an individual objects

Comment: well, you can't do much if it is "just a random object"; what is it *actually*?

Comment: @MarcGravell he said "of the class" which seems clear to mean "object1 is an instance of the class." In context, I'd assume the class being the object which contains the provided code.

Comment: Do you mean to want to make a payment as some atomic transfer; the decrement 3000 and the increment 3000 either both succeed or both fail? To use the database terms, you want to "start a transaction in c#, then transfer the money, then commit the transaction" ?

Comment: How about `object1.Transfer(object2, 2000);` ? You need a way to resolve account numbers to actual objects if you want to update those objects. "lose objects" in memory has no such resolution mechanism unless you keep track of the objects and build one yourself.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen that is my goal, but i have to do that by using their accountNumbers

Comment: I added an example to specify which objects i meant @MarcGravell

Comment: ok - you're using bank accounts as the "example" here (or may be the real application - anyway) but you'll need to assure that account has only 1 instance of it, or always call that instance that loaded for that account, in order to use a number (ID) to locate it. The logic here is that you can create a private list/dictionary/hash for the bank object, so when you create a instance for a account number you check if it exists already, if so provide that instance, otherwise create an instance for it - implement that call on the transfer

Comment: @SammuelMiranda that was one of the idea i had, but i taught there might be a better solution, thanks for clarification

Comment: Note: `double` should *never* be used for this kind of scenario. I get it that this isn't "real", but: important to know!

Comment: @MarcGravell why is that so? Would you mind explaining it please?

Comment: `double` is a binary floating point type, which means that it has precision that is tightly linked to powers of 2, on both sides of the decimal point. While it can easily store 0.5 (1/2) accurately, it cannot store 0.1 precisely and will store something close.  `decimal` is a base 10 floating point value which means that precision is tightly linked to the digits we humans use. It can store both 0.5 and 0.1 precisely.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks for the info!

Comment: i see - it's still the best way to do it, otherwise you can have multiple instances of the same account, but you wouldn't know which one has the updated balance.

Comment: also, perhaps the best approach here would be to not store the credit info on a class instance, and get it directly from the database (of file, or wherever you're storing it), operate the transfer (if possible) and return the true/false response (or maybe the current value) since you might have this program running multple instances over the same data - that approach would work on a service model (single instance on server) to ensure only 1 instance of a account is been used, otherwise, operate directly on the data storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do here is:

- you have multiple objects of some type (perhaps called `Account`), each of which has an identity defined by `accountNumber`
- when transferring funds, you want to look up a *different* account by number, and access *that*

Now: there is no automatic pre-build index of objects by their `accountNumber`. That is something *you would need to add separately*. For example, you might have a `Dictionary<string, Account>`, that you add each instance to:

```cs
var foo = new Account { accoutNumber = "12391", Credit = 420 };
var bar = new Account { accoutNumber = "58u98:a24", Credit = 9000 };

var accounts = new Dictionary<string, Account>();
accounts.Add(foo.accoutNumber , foo);
accounts.Add(bar.accoutNumber , bar);
// etc
```

Now, we can obtain accounts by their identity:

```cs
if (!accounts.TryGetValue(someAccountId, out var someAccount))
{
    throw new KeyNotFoundException("Target bank account not found");
}
// here, someAccount is the one we want by someAccountId
someAccount.DoSomething();
```

This, however, presents a problem; you wouldn't normally expect each individual `Account` object to keep hold of the entire set of accounts; you *could* have some account management type (which maintains the dictionary) perform *both* lookups and perform *both* deltas:

```cs
if (!accounts.TryGetValue(fromId, out var from))
{
    throw new KeyNotFoundException("Source bank account not found");
}
if (!accounts.TryGetValue(toId, out var to))
{
    throw new KeyNotFoundException("Destination bank account not found");
}
if (from.Balance < amount)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Insufficient funds in source account");
}
from.AddBalance(-amount);
to.AddBalance(amount);
```

Note that this is **not** thread-safe. I'm guessing threading isn't a concern for what you're doing.

The alternative would be to *pass in* the accounts lookup to your method. This could the dictionary itself, or some helper service:

```cs
object1.Transfer("7845213154/1448", 2000, accounts);
```

and have the `Transfer` method do the lookup internally, after whatever validation you need:

```cs
public void Transfer(decimal amount, string accountNumber, Dictionary<string, Account> accounts)
{
    if (!accounts.TryGetValue(accountNumber, out var to))
    {
        throw new KeyNotFoundException("Destination bank account not found");
    }
    if (amount > credit)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Insufficient funds in source account");
    }
    AddBalance(-amount);
    to.AddBalance(amount);
}
```

Again, this is not thread-safe in any way, and is not transactional etc.

Comment: thread-safety isn't something i have to concern about with this code, but thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

Would go something like this (refine some rules here and there about validation of account numbers and such).

```
public class Bank
{
    private static global::System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, global::Bank> accounts = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, global::Bank>(10000);
    private string accountNumber;
    private decimal credit;
    public string AccountNumber { get { return this.accountNumber; } }
    public decimal Credit { get { return this.credit; } }
    public void addBalance(decimal amount) { this.credit += amount; }
    public void vyber(int amount) { if (amount <= credit) { this.credit -= amount; } }

    public static global::Bank GetAccount(string number)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(number)) { return null; }
        else
        {
            global::Bank bank = global::Bank.accounts[number];
            if (bank == null) { bank = new global::Bank(number); }
            return bank;
        }
    }

    public void transfer(decimal amount, string number)
    {
        if (amount <= credit && number != this.accountNumber)
        {
            global::Bank bank = global::Bank.GetAccount(number);
            if (bank == null) { throw new global::System.ArgumentException("Not Found"); }
            else
            {
                this.credit -= amount;
                bank.addBalance(amount);
            }
        }
    }

    private Bank(string number) { this.accountNumber = number; }
}
```